# How to Force different locale language for android app?

Tags: android

Regardless the device OS language, My need is to force the app locale to fit my needs which are: translated strings, and layout rtl/ltr to be per app variant. 
I would like to know how to correctly do this. 
as we can see there is a lot of confusion on the web, and  no formal answer for doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most correct approach to do so is to firstable understand the concept of:

1. [Locale](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale)
2. [Configuration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration)
3. [Resources](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources)
4. [BaseContext](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context) and [ContextWrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/ContextWrapper)

**Note that:**
There are 3 types of [Context.getResources] layers:

1. Top-level resources (ex: manifest activity name)
2. Application resources
3. Activity resources

So, changing the Application layer won't affect the activity layer.

**And:**
If you wish to support Android 6 you should use .apk file
and not .aab (android app bundle). 
This is because in Android 6 you can only choose one default locale in settings, and then the .aab will download **ONLY** the required configuration resources:

 Let us assume we use strings.xml in English as our default language, and translate it into Hebrew using other strings-iw.xml 
If the Android 6 device is configured on English as its primary and only language, .aab will only deliver the regular English strings.xml resource.
**OR:**
If it is possible, you can use only one default strings.xml with the required language.

## The solution:

> In your BaseActivity and also on your Application class:

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        val constrainedBaseCtx = LocaleUtil.constrainConfigurationLocale(newBase)
        super.attachBaseContext(constrainedBaseCtx)
    }

    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        val constrainedConfiguration = LocaleUtil.constrainConfigurationLocale(newConfig)
        super.onConfigurationChanged(constrainedConfiguration)
    }

    override fun createConfigurationContext(overrideConfiguration: Configuration): Context {
        val constrainedConf = LocaleUtil.constrainConfigurationLocale(overrideConfiguration)
        return super.createConfigurationContext(constrainedConf)
    }
}
```

> Use your Locale Util:

```
/**
 * Helps to change locales configuration for [Context] objects.
 * Remember that there are 3 types of [Context.getResources] layers:
 *
 * 1. Top-level resources (ex: manifest activity name)
 *
 * 2. Application resources
 *
 * 3. Activity resources
 *
 * So, changing the Application layer won't affect the activity layer.
 */
object LocaleUtil {

const val DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = "iw"
const val DEFAULT_COUNTRY = "il"

/**
 * Constraint This [context] Locale.
 * @param constrainedCountry - the country to match the activity for
 * @param constrainedLanguage - the language inside that country to match the activity for
 * @return new / same instance configured [Context]. (depends on Android OS version)
 */
fun constrainConfigurationLocale(
    context: Context,
    constrainedCountry: String = DEFAULT_COUNTRY,
    constrainedLanguage: String = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE
) : Context {
    val newConf = constrainConfigurationLocale(
        context.resources.configuration,
        constrainedCountry,
        constrainedLanguage
    )
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1)
        context.createConfigurationContext(newConf)
    else
        context
}

/**
 * Constraint This [configuration] Locale.
 * @param constrainedCountry - the country to match the activity for
 * @param constrainedLanguage - the language inside that country to match the activity for
 * @return new / same instance of [Configuration]. (depends on Android OS version)
 */
fun constrainConfigurationLocale(
    currentConfiguration: Configuration,
    constrainedCountry: String = DEFAULT_COUNTRY,
    constrainedLanguage: String = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE
) : Configuration {

    val configuration = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1)
        Configuration(currentConfiguration)
    else
        currentConfiguration
    val synthesizedLocale = Locale(constrainedLanguage, constrainedCountry)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        val oldLocales = configuration.locales
        @Suppress("UNNECESSARY_NOT_NULL_ASSERTION")
        if (!oldLocales.isEmpty) {
            if (!oldLocales[0].language!!.contentEquals(synthesizedLocale.language)) {
                var newLocales = arrayOfNulls<Locale>(oldLocales.size() + 1)
                newLocales[0] = synthesizedLocale // first locale determines layout direction
                var deductionCount = 0
                for (i in 0 until oldLocales.size()) {
                    if (newLocales[0]?.language?.contentEquals(oldLocales[i].language) != true) // add only different locale if not null
                        newLocales[i + 1 - deductionCount] = oldLocales[i]
                    else {
                        val temp = arrayOfNulls<Locale>(newLocales.size - 1)
                        for (j in 0..i) {
                            temp[j] = newLocales[j]
                        }
                        newLocales = temp
                        deductionCount++
                    }
                }
                configuration.locales = LocaleList(*newLocales)
            }
        } else {
            configuration.locales = LocaleList(synthesizedLocale)
        }
    } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION", "UNNECESSARY_NOT_NULL_ASSERTION")
        if (configuration.locale == null || !synthesizedLocale.language!!.contentEquals(configuration.locale.language!!))
            configuration.setLocale(synthesizedLocale)
    }
    return configuration
}
}
```

Comment: Sometimes we receive `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at `temp[j] = newLocales[j]` so we replace this reordering logic with code from hidden `LocaleList(Locale, LocaleList)` constructor